# how i can show image after image writing

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying simple code that read an image and convert it to grey scale then show both of them, and finally save the grey scale image and display it after saving. The problem is that `cv2.imshow` (image show) for saved image doesn't work.

The images before image writing are displayed correctly and the image saved correctly in the same path but can't be displayed using `cv2.imshow`.

'''
**python**
'''

```
import cv2  

img=cv2.imread('cover.jpg') 
cv2.imshow('image', img)  

img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)  
cv2.imshow('image_grey', img_grey) 

savedimage='new.jpg'  
cv2.imwrite('new.jpg',img_grey)  
cv2.imshow('testsavedimage',savedimage) 

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**I receive error for showing saved image**

```
File "C:/1.py", line 8, in <module>
cv2.imshow('testsavedimage',savedimage)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s
```

Comment: Change `savedimage` on second last line to `img_grey`

Comment: Change `cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY` to `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help get more answered to you question please provide a description of the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

savedimage is just a string in this case.  If you want to make sure that your grey scale image was saved properly, you need to first read it back into a Mat object:

```
    cv2.imwrite('new.jpg',img_grey)
    savedImg = cv2.imread('new.jpg')
    cv2.imshow('testsavedimage', savedImg)
```

Hope this helps.

(PS @Mark Setchel is right, you should be using cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY here.  This is because imread() and imshow() default to BGR colorspace, not RGB)